# Multi-threading PySpark, Could not serialize object exception

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, pyspark

**_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object:
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation.
SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.**

Super simple **EXAMPLE** app to try and run some calculations in parallel.  Works (sometimes) but most times crashes with the above exception.

I don't think I have nested RDD, but the part about not being able to use the sparkContext in workers is worrisome since I think I need that to achieve some level of parallelism.  If I can't use the sparkContext in the worker threads, how do I get the computational results back?

At this point I still expect it to be serialized, and was going to enable the parallel run after this.  But can't even get the serialized multi-threaded version to run....

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import threading

THREADED = True. # Set this to false and it always works but is sequential

content_file = "file:///usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.0/README.md"
sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")
content = sc.textFile(content_file).cache() # For the non-threaded version

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, letter, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.letter = letter

    def run(self):
        print(f"Starting: {self.letter}")
        nums[self.letter] = content.filter(lambda s: self.letter in s).count() # SPOILER self.letter turns out to be the problem
        print(f"{self.letter}: {nums[self.letter]}")

nums = {}
if THREADED:
    threads = []
    for char in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
        letter = chr(char)
        threads.append(Worker(letter, name=letter))

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

else:
    for char in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
        letter = chr(char)
        nums[letter] = content.filter(lambda s: letter in s).count()
        print(f"{letter}: {nums[letter]}")

print(nums)
```

Even when I change the code to use one thread at a time

```
    threads = []
    for char in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
        letter = chr(char)
        thread = Worker(letter, name=letter)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

It raises the same exception, I guess because it is trying to get the results back in a worker thread and not the main thread (where the SparkContext is declared).

I need to be able to wait on several values simultaneously if spark is going to provide any benefit here.

---

The real problem I'm trying to solve looks like this:

```
__________RESULT_________
   ^         ^         ^
   A         B         C
a1 ^ a2   b1 ^ b2   c1 ^ c2...
```

To get my result I want to calculate A B and C in parallel, and each of those pieces will have to calculate a1, a2, a3, .... in parallel.  I'm breaking it into threads so I can request multiple values simultaneously so that spark can run the computation in parallel.

---

I created the sample above simply because I want to get the threading correct, I'm not trying to figure out how to count the # of lines with a character in it.  But this seemed super simple to vet the threading aspect.

---

This little change fixes things right up.  self.letter was blowing up in the lambda, dereferencing it before the filter call removed the crash

```
    def run(self):
        print(f"Starting: {self.letter}")
        letter = self.letter
        nums[self.letter] = content.filter(lambda s: letter in s).count()
        print(f"{self.letter}: {nums[self.letter]}")
```

Comment: You should not use Spark + manual threads. Spark does all the thread/distribution handling for you

Comment: That is exactly the opposite of what I have read.  There is no way to wait for N result sets if those jobs have not been submitted to Spark to be run in parallel.  I've also read that after I have the threading stuff done I have to turn on the FAIR scheduler to actually get multiprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exception says

> It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a
> broadcast variable, action, or transformation

In your case the reference to the `SparkContext` is held by the following line:

```py
nums[self.letter] = self.content.filter(lambda s: self.letter in s).count()
```

in this line, you define a filter (which counts as a transformation) using the following lambda expression:

```py
lambda s: self.letter in s
```

The Problem with this expression is: You reference the member variable `letter` of the object-reference `self`. To make this reference available during the execution of your batch, Spark needs to serialize the object `self`. But this object holds not only the member `letter`, but also `content`, which is a Spark-RDD (and every Spark-RDD holds a reference to the SparkContext it was created from).

To make the lambda serializable, you have to ensure not to reference anything that is not serializable inside it. The easiest way to achieve that, given your example, is to define a local variable based on the member `letter`:

```py
    def run(self):
        print(f"Starting: {self.letter}")
        letter = self.letter
        nums[self.letter] = self.content.filter(lambda s: letter in s).count()
        print(f"{self.letter}: {nums[self.letter]}")
```

## The Why

To understand *why* we can't do this, we have to understand what Spark does with every transformation in the background.

Whenever you have some piece of code like this:

```py
sc = SparkContext(<connection information>)
```

You're creating a "Connection" to the Spark-Master. It may be a simple in-process local Spark-Master or a Spark-Master running on a whole different server.

Given the `SparkContext`-Object, we can define where our pipeline should get it's data from. For this example, let's say we want to read our data from a text-file (just like in your question:

```py
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.0/README.md")
```

As I mentioned before, the `SparkContext` is more or less a "Connection" to the Spark-Master. The URL we specify as the location of our text-file **must be accessable from the Spark-Master**, not from the system you're executing the python-script on!

Based on the Spark-RDD we created, we can now define how the data should be processed. Let's say we want to count only lines that contain a given string `"Hello World"`:

```py
linesThatContainHelloWorld = rdd.filter(lambda line: "Hello World" in line).count()
```

What Spark does once we call a terminal function (a computation that yields a result, like `count()` in this case) is that it serializes the function we passed to `filter`, transfers the serialized data to the Spark-Workers (which may run on a totally different server) and these Spark-Workers deserialize that function to be able to execute the given function.

That means that this piece of code: `lambda line: "Hello World" in line` will actually **not** be executed inside the Python-Process you're currently in, but on the Spark-Workers.

Things start to get trickier (for Spark) whenever we reference a variable from the upper scope inside one of our transformations:

```py
stringThatALineShouldContain = "Hello World"
linesThatContainHelloWorld = rdd.filter(lambda line: stringThatALineShouldContain in line).count()
```

Now, Spark not only has to serialize the given function, but also the referenced variable `stringThatALineShouldContain` from the upper scope. In this simple example, this is no problem, since the variable `stringThatALineShouldContain` is serializable.

But whenever we try to access something that is not serializable or simply holds a reference to something that is not serialize, Spark will complain.

For example:

```py
stringThatALineShouldContain = "Hello World"
badExample = (sc, stringThatALineShouldContain) # tuple holding a reference to the SparkContext

linesThatContainHelloWorld = rdd.filter(lambda line: badExample[1] in line).count()
```

Since the function now references `badExample`, Spark tries to serialize this variable and complains that it holds a reference to the `SparkContext`.

This not only applies to the `SparkContext`, but to everything that is not serializable, such as Connection-Objects to Databases, File-Handles and many more.
If, for any reason, you have to do something like this, you should only reference an object that contains information of how to create that unserializable object.

### An example

#### Invalid example

```py
dbConnection = MySQLConnection("mysql.example.com") # Not sure if this class exists, only for the example
rdd.filter(lambda line: dbConnection.insertIfNotExists("INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES (?)", line)
```

#### Valid example

```py
# note that this is still "bad code", since the connection is never cleared. But I hope you get the idea

class LazyMySQLConnection:
    connectionString = None
    actualConnection = None

    def __init__(self, connectionString):
        self.connectionString = connectionString
    
    def __getstate__(self):
        # tell pickle (the serialization library Spark uses for transformations) that the actualConnection member is not part of the state
        state = dict(self.__dict__)
        del state["actualConnection"]
        return state
    
    def getOrCreateConnection(self):
        if not self.actualConnection:
            self.actualConnection = MySQLConnection(self.connectionString)
        return self.actualConnection

lazyDbConnection = LazyMySQLConnection("mysql.example.com")
rdd.filter(lambda line: lazyDbConnection.getOrCreateConnection().insertIfNotExists("INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES (?)", line)

# remember, the lambda we supplied for the filter will be executed on the Spark-Workers, so the connection will be etablished from each Spark-Worker!
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use (Py)Spark in a way it is not intended to be used. You're mixing up plain-python data processing with spark-processing where you could completely realy on spark.

The Idea with Spark (and other Data Processing Frameworks) is, that you define how your data should be processed and all the multithreading + distribution stuff is just a independent "configuration".

Also, I don't really see what you would like to gain by using multiple threads.
Every Thread would:

1. Have to read every single character from your input file
2. Check if the current line contains the letter that was assigned to this thread
3. Count

This would (if it worked) yield a correct result, sure, but is inefficient, since there would be many threads fighting for those read operations on that file (remember, every thread would have to read the COMPLETE file in the first place, the be able to filter based on its assigned letter).

Work with spark, not against it, to get the most out of it.

```py
# imports and so on

content_file = "file:///usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.0/README.md"
sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")

rdd = sc.textFile(content_file) # read from this file
rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: [letter for letter in line]) # forward every letter of each line to the next operator

# initialize the letterRange "outside" of spark so we reduce the runtime-overhead
relevantLetterRange = [chr(char) for char in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda letter: letter in relevantLetterRange)

rdd = rdd.keyBy(lambda letter: letter) # key by the letter itself
countsByKey = rdd.countByKey() # count by key
```

You can of course simply write this in one chain:

```py
# imports and so on

content_file = "file:///usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.0/README.md"
sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")

relevantLetterRange = [chr(char) for char in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]

countsByKey = sc.textFile(content_file)\
    .flatMap(lambda line: [letter for letter in line])\
    .filter(lambda letter: letter in relevantLetterRange)\
    .keyBy(lambda letter: letter)
    .countByKey()
```

Comment: This is **EXAMPLE** code, my actual code will be computing different things.  A is made up of 3  parts.  Those 3 parts are made of 2-3 computations each, all of them are querying different data points.  I'm trying to get the threading right so that I can do REAL work.  I want all of the calculations to go on in parallel, this is just a way to shake out the mechanism before I put the real algos into separate threads.  But if I can't wait on all the results in parallel, then Spark won't cut it for me.  I'm not asking how to solve this example more efficiently.

Comment: @boatcoder well, then the answer is: you can't reference the SparkContext from inside any function (or lambda) in your rdd, since it's not serializable. You're holding a reference to the SparkContext through your filter lambda `lambda s: self.letter in s` (youre referencing a member of `self`, because of that PySpark tries the serialize the whole `self` object, which holds a reference to the SparkContext via `content`).

Comment: Wow, self.letter was it!  moved it out as `letter = self.letter` and `filter(lambda s: letter in s)` and it just works and does things out of order which shows the threads are doing as expected.  Talk about subtle!   Want to make this the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @boatcoder I'll add it as an answer when I'm back at my PC :)